# aws lambda throwing Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named '_portaudio'

Tags: python, aws-lambda, pyaudio, portaudio

I currently have some python code that I have stored in a zip file with my dependencies. The code compiles and works fine locally in Visual Studio Code. However, when I go to upload the file onto a Lambda function, I get this error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named '_portaudio'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

I am using pyaudio and I have never had any interaction with portaudio. What should I do?

Attached is a screenshot of my zip file:
[image: Screenshot]

**Image Updates**

[image: New Lambda Layer]

[image: Zip File]

Comment: Is it the same version of Python? `_portaudio.cp38-win_amd64.pyd` is for Python 3.8, Windows and on 64-bit x86 architecture. If any of them differs on AWS, you will need a different file.

Comment: @tevemadar lambda is on python 3.8 i believe

Comment: The problem is not necessarily the Python version. Your libraries need to be "compiled" for linux kernel and amd64 architecture. So your libs for Windows won't work. I have written a detailed answer how to get dependencies for Lambda: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67558466/190823

Comment: That was a 3-element list. If version is correct, operating system and CPU architecture still remain.

Comment: @Jens I attached some screenshots above. I followed your directions and the same portaudio error occurred. What can I do?

Comment: @Juliette Did you use the Docker container?